# Can I rerun failed mappers in EMR

Tags: mapreduce, emr, elastic-map-reduce, amazon-emr

I just woke up to a failed 16h long EMR MpaReduce job that failed because of a 'few' mappers that timed out.

Is there a way to rerun only those failed mappers (yes it makes sense in my specific use case)? How?

Answer (score 1):

Too late for a real-time question. In general - No.

But sometimes it's possible. If you can take the trouble of finding out exactly what splits were being processed by the failed mappers (from the mapper logs) - and if this was a map-only job - then you could create a custom job that went only after the failed splits. Very hard in general - especially since splits typically span files.